# How do I get the sum of frequency count based on two columns?

Tags: r

Assuming that the dataframe is stored as `someData`, and is in the following format:

```
ID                Team                Games                Medal
1                 Australia           1992 Summer          NA
2                 Australia           1994 Summer          Gold
3                 Australia           1992 Summer          Silver
4                 United States       1991 Winter          Gold
5                 United States       1992 Summer          Bronze
6                 Singapore           1991 Summer          NA
```

How would I count the frequencies of the medal, based on the Team - while excluding `NA` as an variable. But at the same time, the total frequency of each country should be summed, rather than displayed separately for `Gold`, `Silver` and `Bronze`.

In other words, I am trying to display the **total** number of medals PER country, with the exception of `NA`.

I have tried something like this:

```
library(plyr)
counts <- ddply(olympics, .(olympics$Team, olympics$Medal), nrow)
names(counts) <- c("Country", "Medal", "Freq")
counts
```

But this just gives me a massive table of every medal for every country separately, including NA.

What I would like to do is the following:

```
Australia            2
United States        2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Medal)) %>%
  count(Team)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Team              n
#  <fct>         <int>
#1 Australia         2
#2 United States     2
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Is there a way to sort by the NUMBER OF MEDALS rather than alphabetically for the team.

Comment: @NaumanShahid  After the count, do `arrange` i.e. `count(Team) %>% arrange(n)`

Comment: I tried that but it seems to be ascending order rather than descending. Am I missing something?

Comment: @NaumanShahid If you need in descending use `arrange(desc(n))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in base R with `table` and `colSums`

```
colSums(table(someData$Medal, someData$Team))
    Australia     Singapore United States 
            2             0             2
```

**Data**

```
someData = read.table(text="ID        Team        Games         Medal
1                 Australia           '1992 Summer'          NA
2                 Australia           '1994 Summer'          Gold
3                 Australia           '1992 Summer'          Silver
4                 'United States'     '1991 Winter'          Gold
5                 'United States'     '1992 Summer'          Bronze
6                 Singapore           '1991 Summer'          NA",
header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Only as a zero.